# Adding & Removing arrays from large objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Each user has an array in an object(this main object can have as many as 3,000 arrays in it at any time, that keeps growing).

In the array contain a username and the last 4 message the user sent (messages are hashed with a fast hashing method). Older messages are pushed out.

When an new message is added to the array all elements get check to see if there equal. Would there be a better way of doing this. Im sure have a massive object with nested arrays is a bit slow?

```
let messagescont = {}
 if (!messagescont.hasOwnProperty("a" + message.author.id)){
 //add new user to object
 messagescont["a" + message.author.id] = [{data})
 }else{
 //user has object
  messagescont["a" + message.author.id].push({data})
     if(messagescont["a" + message.author.id].length > 4){
         messagescont["a" + message.author.id].splice(0,1)
         let hashtable = [];
         messagescont["a" + message.author.id].forEach(messages => 
         hashtable.push(messages.data.hash))
         const arraysame = !!hashtable.reduce(function (a,b){ return (a === b)? a : NaN;});
     }
 }
```

The data object looks like that

```
    const data = {
        hash: hashCode(message.content),  
        username: message.author.username,
        userid: message.author.id,
    }
```

That array/object/array mess

```
   {username [{data},{data},{data}],
   username2 [{data},{data},{data} }
```

Comment: So do you actually have an issue with this code? Do you see performance issues?

Comment: Mmm, can you explain what the hash check is for in the first place?

Comment: There no issue with the code, but could it be made more efficient

Comment: The  hash check is uses to make a massive message much small. eg from 300+ chars to around 10 with little CPU as possible

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. I mean, what do you use `arraysame` for?

Comment: if all the hashes in the array are the same //then do something

Answer (score 0):

Like @epascarello implied in the comment: if there's no measurable performance issue, don't worry about it.  Nevertheless, here's a slightly (micro-)optimized version.

```
const messagesPerAuthor = {};
const contKey = "a" + message.author.id; // Avoid recomputing this value 6 times
if (!messagesPerAuthor[contKey]) {
  messagesPerAuthor[contKey] = [];
}
messagesPerAuthor[contKey].push({ data });
if (messagesPerAuthor[contKey].length > 4) {
  messagesPerAuthor[contKey].splice(0, 1);
}
let hasDuplicate = false;
if (messagesPerAuthor[contKey].length > 1) {
  // No need to bother with the `.some` indication if there's only one message
  const hashesSeen = {}; // could also be a `new Set()` for more modern browsers
  hasDuplicate = messagesPerAuthor[contKey].some(message => {
    const seen = hashesSeen[message.data.hash]; // true if we had seen this hash before
    hashesSeen[messages.data.hash] = true;
    return seen; // returning a truthy value will early-exit the `some` loop.
  });
}
```

Using a plain `for(var i = 0; i < messagesPerAuthor[contKey].length; i++)` style loop with `break` would probably be faster than the `some` stuff, but since FP style is in vogue... :)